# Python Horizontal Bar Double Graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I made in Python a horizontal bar plot, with a bar coming from left to right:

[image: Bar Graph]

I would like to add an additional horizontal bar, on the same horizontal plane of the previous bar, this time coming from right to left. Both horizontal bars should be present at the same time.

Does anybody have any idea on how to do that? If I use the reverse function everything is reversed, but I need to reverse only the new specific bar without changing anything else.

Ideally, on the new picture the new bar graph would come from the right and stop at 25, with error bars from 23 to 27 (-/+ 2).

Here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(9.5, 2.7))

# Create horizontal bars
plt.barh(0, 18,height=0.2,facecolor='orange',edgecolor='black',linewidth=2)

plt.errorbar(x=[18], y=[0], xerr=[2],color='black',fmt='none',linewidth=5,zorder=4)

plt.xticks(np.arange(10, 30+1, 1.0),fontsize=14)
plt.yticks([])

plt.xlim(10, 30)
plt.ylim(-.13, .13)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What would be the value of your red bar? For example, your orange bar has value ~21. On this x axis, a bar coming from the right doesn't have meaning. Are you hoping to have a new, inverted axis that starts from 0 on the right as well?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I modified a bit the question specifying the new bar I would need.

Comment: `plt.barh(0, 5, left=25, height=0.2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `left` to specify where the bar should start, then pass a negative `width` for your bar to make it extend right to left. Since the right side of the window will also change with your data, you might also want to make that some sort of parameter i.e. `x_max`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_max = 30

plt.figure(figsize=(9.5, 2.7))

# Create horizontal bars
plt.barh(0, 18,height=0.2,facecolor='orange',edgecolor='black',linewidth=2)
plt.errorbar(x=[18], y=[0], xerr=[2],color='black',fmt='none',linewidth=5,zorder=4)

# new code: use left to specify the start position, then make its width negative
# to extend right to left
plt.barh(0, -5, height=0.2, left=x_max, facecolor='red',edgecolor='black',linewidth=2)
# place error bars the same as you did for the above.
plt.errorbar(x=[x_max - 5], y=[0], xerr=[2],color='black',fmt='none',linewidth=5,zorder=4)


plt.xticks(np.arange(10, 30+1, 1.0),fontsize=14)
plt.yticks([])

plt.xlim(10, x_max)
plt.ylim(-.13, .13)

plt.show()
```

[image]